# Accessing and editing a dictionary from multiple files

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Can dictionaries be accessed by multiple files in Python 2.7?
One can import classes and functions from other files, but can the same be done with dictionaries?
I might have a file with a dictionary and an assortment of functions that can be used by other files to do things with the dictionary, but is it necessary to write a function for every single thing I might want to do?  I would like to be able to do basic things, like printing part of the dictionary, from another file.
Essentially, what I want to know is:  Does importing a file also import a dictionary within the file and if not, how can I?

If this *is* possible, I would also like to know if the original dictionary can be edited from another file.  As well as printing part of it, could I then change a value in the original dictionary?

I have been unable to find anything about this on the internet.  Please educate me, stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, dictionaries are not special and can be imported into other modules, just like anything else you define in a Python module. Like functions and classes, dictionaries are Python objects, and importing does nothing but create a new reference in the current module to values you imported.

You can manipulate the dictionary from anywhere; dictionaries are mutable structures, once you have a reference to it you can alter the keys and values of that dictionary.

Comment: Thank you.  Would I access the dictionary with `filename.dictionary` or just the dictionary's name?

Comment: @Erebus9997: That depends on how you imported it. `from modulename import dictionary` adds `dictionary` to your local namespace, while `import modulename` adds `modulename` to your local namespace and then you'd have to use `modulename.dictionary` to reference the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

file1.py

```
d = {'a':5}
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import d
d['a'] += 3
def whatever():
   pass
```

file3.py

```
from file2 import whatever
from file1 import d
print d
#now if you wanted the unmodified value from file1 you could reload it
import file1
reload(file1)
from file1 import d
print d  #note only in this file is d reverted ... any other place would have the modified dictionary
```

Comment: Why the reload? You didn't change the source code. The `reload()` is just confusing matters here.

Comment: to show how to revert back to the unchanged d that was originally in file1

Comment: Right, you may want to make that explicit; you are correct, `reload()` will re-execute `d`, but other modules with a reference to `d` will *not* see the change unless they instead used `import file1; print file1.d`.

Comment: How about if I want to use d['a'] from file2.py based upon a variable e.g. def fun(x,y):